# Unable to save edited torrc in Tails

Tags: configuration, persistent

Logged in as admin then used:

sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc

ExcludeNodes {us},{de},{fr}
ExcludeExitNodes {us},{au},{ca},{nz},{gb},{fr}

CTRL-X

sudo systemctl restart tor

This works for the current session ONLY but does not save once rebooted.

Is it possible to have the torrc saved in persistent?

Answer (score 0):

As tails is intended to leave no traces, in general everything is deleted.

You may save your torrc in ~/Persistent/ and start tor manually with -f FILE or use the tails-persistence-setup tool.

See https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/persistence/